# Parsing HTML documents using lxml in python

Tags: python, lxml

I just downloaded lxml to parse broken HTML documents. I was reading through the documentation of lxml but could not find that given a HTML document, how do we just retrieve the text in the document using lxml. I will be obliged if someone could help me with this.

Comment: lxml might be a bit low level for this, have you considered [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)?

Comment: I have tried BeatuifulSoup but it does not handle broken HTML as well as lxml!!! Please let me know the syntax

Comment: By "retrieve the text in the document" do you mean retrieve text inside a particular element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple:

```
from lxml import html
html_document = ... #Get your document contents here from a file or whatever

tree = html.fromstring(html_document)
text_document = tree.text_content()
```

If you only want the content from specific blocks (e.g. the body block), then you can access them using xpath expressions:

```
body_tags = tree.xpath('//body')
if body_tags:
  body = body_tags[0]
  text_document = body.text_content()
else:
  text_document = ''
```

Comment: Is there a way to only read the text in the title and the text in the body using lxml